# Customizing Notifier.Plugin Navigation with Xamarin Forms(Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

we were using the Notifier Plugin in our application to show the Notification for our Xamarin Forms application.
Notifier Plugin URL: https://github.com/edsnider/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Notifier

For customizing the Notification Navigation with Android Platform,

Changes made in Plugin.LocalNotifications.Android Source as :

1. In LocalNotificationsImplementation as "var resultIntent = new Intent(Application.Context,typeof(RedirectActivity));"
2. In RedirectActivity Activity, we have included "MessagingCenter.Send("SampleAppNotificationNavigation", "RedirectToNavigationPage");"

Changes made in MyApplication.Android Source as :

3. In our Android application we subscribed messaging center as " MessagingCenter.Subscribe(this, "RedirectToNavigationPage", message =>
           {
               LoadApplication(new NextPage());
           });"

Note: Based on the suggestion from Native to Forms Page Navigation we have implmented the same. 
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms

4. In our core project App page we have included as "
   public class NextPage : Application
   {
       public NextPage()
       {
           MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ConfigureServer());
       }
   }"

**Everything is working as expected (till ConfigureServer page constructor and intializecomponent() riased )  but failed to launch the ConfigureServer Page.**

Kindly guide us to proceed further.

Thanks in advance.